# heroku local not displaying router logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have a Ruby on Rails application running successfully on Heroku in production. When I look at the logs for the production environment I see logs for the `router`, `web` dynos, and `worker` dynos. However, when I launch the application locally (`heroku local`) and make some HTTP requests, I see only logs for the web and workers -- i.e. the request is being successfully routed, but I don't see the logs. What do I have to do to see the router logs?

Not sure what code is useful here, it's a large application.

Comment: Does your problem still persist?

Comment: I'm not longer working with that system... Should I remove this question?

Comment: No don’t remove it. Let’s hope someone answers the problem and adds value to the SO community.